# SQL Server 2008 Trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger

New to triggers. I have two tables. One for users & other for circulated mails.

The circulated mails table has [Sender, Receiver...] users table has [Personal Number, Names, Email]. when we have an insert in the circulated mails, the trigger should look at the Receiver (Number) and compare with similar number in users and pick the email address. The trigger also picks the Sender (number) and picks similar number in Users table and uses the name.

I have configured xp_sendmail and test mails are going out without any issue.

This is what I have done:

```
CREATE TRIGGER newMail
ON Circulated Mails
FOR INSERT
AS
   declare @Sender varchar(10)
   declare @body varchar(3000) 

declare @Email varchar(1000)

SELECT @Email = (select Email from Users where [Personal No]=
  (select  Receiver from [Circulated Mails])),
  @Sender=(select Names from Users where [Personal No]=
  (select  Sender from [Circulated Mails])),
 SET @body =
'You have new Mail in the IRMS System'
'Sender ' + @Sender + ' 
'Login into the system '

 --xp_sendmail is the extended sproc used to send the mail
   EXEC master..xp_sendmail 
            @recipients = @Email,
            @subject = 'You have New Mail',
            @message = @body

 END 
GO
```

I implemented Aaron's code and this now gives a syntax error at GO!

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.newMail
ON dbo.[Circulated Mails]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) RETURN;

  DECLARE @sender VARCHAR(10), @body VARCHAR(3000), @Email VARCHAR(1000);

  DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
    FOR SELECT r.Email, s.Names
    FROM inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS r
    ON r.[Personal No] = i.Receiver
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS s
    ON s.[Personal No] = i.Sender;

  OPEN c;
  FETCH c INTO @Email, @Sender;

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

    SET @body = 'You have new Mail in the IRMS System'
     + 'Sender ' + @Sender + 'Login into the system ';

    EXEC master..xp_sendmail 
            @recipients = @Email,
            @subject = 'You have New Mail',
            @message = @body;

    FETCH c INTO @Email, @Sender;
  END

  CLOSE c; DEALLOCATE c;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'irms', @recipients =@Email, @subject ='Mail',@body=@body, @body_format='HTML';  

END
GO
```

Comment: Why did you add an additional sendmail command *after* the loop? I don't get a syntax error here. Where exactly are you running the code?

Comment: am running on ma development laptop

Comment: I don't mean what computer. I mean in Management Studio? A query editor window or some visual query designer? Etc.

Comment: @Aaron, i have run the query in the editor and getting this: The module 'newMail' depends on the missing object 'master..xp_sendmail'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.

Comment: @Aaron...i have removed the duplication and its working well..

Comment: the querry executes well..but when i check on the email of the receiver, nothing has come in..

Comment: you need to troubleshoot Database Mail, which is a completely different question.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems with the trigger you have written.

1. There is no tie to the actual row(s) that fired the trigger. You need to identify the relevant rows using the `inserted` pseudo-table. You also need to be aware that you will need to loop in the event that more than one row is inserted in any statement.
2. You're using `xp_sendmail`, which is deprecated. You should be using [Database Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms175887(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) instead.
3. You haven't mentioned the schema in any table reference. [Schema is important](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix). Also you shouldn't have spaces in table names; if this can't be changed, you need to use `[square brackets]` every single time you reference it.

This is probably a lot closer to what you need, minus the switch to Database Mail:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.newMail
ON dbo.[Circulated Mails]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) RETURN;

  DECLARE @sender VARCHAR(10), @body VARCHAR(3000), @Email VARCHAR(1000);

  DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
    FOR SELECT r.Email, s.Names
    FROM inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS r
    ON r.[Personal No] = i.Receiver
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS s
    ON s.[Personal No] = i.Sender;

  OPEN c; FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @Email, @Sender;

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

    SET @body = 'You have new Mail in the IRMS System'
     + 'Sender ' + @Sender + 'Login into the system ';

    EXEC master..xp_sendmail 
            @recipients = @Email,
            @subject = 'You have New Mail',
            @message = @body;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @Email, @Sender;
  END

  CLOSE c; DEALLOCATE c;
END
```

That all said, you really shouldn't be sending e-mails from a trigger IMHO. See the "Performing inappropriate actions" section of this post:

- [Bad habits to kick : abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)